# Grouping historical alerts in tools like graylog, prometheus, grafana etc

Tags: grouping, prometheus, grafana, alerts, graylog

Is there a way to group historical alerts in tools like grafana, graylog, prometheus etc? I'm looking for a tool that could group an alert with historical ones. Same thing may have happened historically and I'd like to see that. Maybe with an option to describe that group. And to create those groups automatically basing on some kind of heuristics. And to create that group also by hand.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try [alerta](https://alerta.io).